# Render an entity reference in a twig template

Tags: theming, 8

I have a field that is an entity reference. I would like to print the entire entity in my controller.

I know I can print a particular field of the entity using something like

```
{{ teacher.field_classrooms.entity.field_classroom_one.value }}
```

but I need to print the whole entity rather than just one field.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 3):

If you install [twig_tweak](https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_tweak), you can load an entity directly from twig:

{{ drupal_entity('node', node.field_classrooms.entity.id) }}

But I would recommend against this.  Drupal has a built in way to render fields, as explained by [zhilevan](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/216025/45409)

Comment: This is the most easy way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

first you should select show *Rendered Entity* in your content type field *Manage Display* section in `admin/structure/types/manage/teacher/display` (I supposed your content type is teacher based on your question), then in your node template  try to render the content field with something like

```
{{ content.field_classrooms }}
```

Comment: you removed "in my controller", but this isn't a content type node. Teacher is my content type, but this specific page of results.

Comment: @Brittany "{{" is twig operator not valid operator in controller!!!, 
now I understand what you want to do,you have custom page and want pass your variables to it?is it right? if this is true please writedown your controller snippet in order to I can help you better.